# UITabBarController - transition from one tab's navigation stack to a view controller of another tab's navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Novice iOS developer here.  I am making a simple tabbed chat application in Swift using a UITabBarController.  For simplicity, let's assume the application only has two tabs, "Contacts" and "Chats".  Each of the two tabs has a navigation controller.

The "Chats" navigation stack begins with a UITableViewController called "ChatsTableViewController" which lists the user's chats.  When the user selects a chat, the app segues to a MessagesViewController which displays the messages for the selected chat.

The "Contacts" navigation stack includes a UITableViewController which lists the user's contacts.  Upon selecting a contact, another view controller is presented modally, asking the user whether they would like to begin a chat with the selected contact, and giving them the option to cancel.  If the user chooses to begin a chat, I would like to transition from this modal view controller to the MessagesViewController of the "Chats" tab, passing the information necessary to display the chat (which I have at the ready in the modal view controller).

When the MessagesViewController loads, regardless of whether we get to it by selecting a chat from the "Chats" tab or by creating a new chat from the "Contacts" tab, it should have a navigation bar at the top with a "Back" button that takes the user to the ChatsTableViewController.

I have done a good deal of searching, but have not found any solutions that fit what I need.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Here is a summary of what I am looking for.

1. Standard way to perform a transition from a view controller in one tab's navigation stack to a view controller (that is not the root view controller in my case) of another tab's navigation stack, while passing relevant information to display in the destination view controller.
2. The view controller I transition to should have a navigation bar with a back button that takes the user to the previous view controller in its navigation stack, just as if they had accessed it from the normal navigation flow of the tab.

**EDIT**: I've found that you can easily switch tabs programmatically using `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = index_of_tab_to_switch_to`, however, this takes me to the first view of the tab and I am still unsure of how I can pass data. Any thoughts on how I can proceed?

Comment: have you got any solution ?